# Rundeck Notification Java Plugin

Tags: rundeck

I am working on a Rundeck Java Notification plugin and would like to use the `STORAGE_PATH_AUTOMATIC_READ` feature to pull in a value from key storage to be used during the job execution. However the rendering option does not seem to do anything during the execution of the plugin. When I print out the value it is not the contents from key storage but just simply the path to the key. Below is the code I am trying to use.

```java
@Plugin(service = "Notification", name = "smSlackNotificationPlugin")
@PluginDescription(title = "SM Slack Notification", description = "SM custom Slack Notification Plugin")
public class SMSlackNotificationPlugin implements NotificationPlugin, DynamicProperties {

    @PluginProperty(name = "example", title = "Example String", description = "Example description")
    private String example;

    @PluginProperty(name = "botkey", 
                    title = "Bot Key", 
                    description = "Bot key test", 
                    required = true)
    @RenderingOptions({
        @RenderingOption(
            key = StringRenderingConstants.SELECTION_ACCESSOR_KEY,
            value = "STORAGE_PATH"
        ),
        @RenderingOption(
            key = StringRenderingConstants.STORAGE_PATH_ROOT_KEY,
            value = "keys/AWS"
        ),
        @RenderingOption(
            // key = "valueConversion",
            key = StringRenderingConstants.VALUE_CONVERSION_KEY,
            value = "STORAGE_PATH_AUTOMATIC_READ"
        )
    })
    private String botkey;
```

The property botkey shows correctly in the UI and lets me select a key from the Key storage, but does not ever read the value from storage. I have checkout out the audit logs for key storage and during the execution of the job nothing tries to access the key in storage. I have tried different variations of the `RenderingOption` but nothing seems to make a difference.

I have not found any examples of that this working and was wondering if anyone has ran into this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Which rundeck version are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.14.1

Comment: Try it this way, I made a groovy-based example totally workable on Java: https://pastebin.com/qagnwXhP

Answer (score 0):

It works in the following way (I made the example on Groovy):

```
@PluginProperty(title="My Key", description = "My description", scope= PropertyScope.Instance, required = false)
    @RenderingOptions([
            @RenderingOption(
                    key = StringRenderingConstants.SELECTION_ACCESSOR_KEY,
                    value = "STORAGE_PATH"
            ),
            @RenderingOption(
                    key = StringRenderingConstants.STORAGE_PATH_ROOT_KEY,
                    value = "keys"
            ),
            @RenderingOption(
                    key = StringRenderingConstants.STORAGE_FILE_META_FILTER_KEY,
                    value = "Rundeck-data-type=password"
            )
    ])
String myKey
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help in my case. Even tried different combinations of the `RenderingOptions` and tried in both groovy and java.